# Delete File 'i' to 'n' With Batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I need to delete some files in a directory. They are all numbered like file1.txt, file2.txt,...,filen.txt

I want to ask users the number of files they want to delete (called x), and just delete from file1.txt to filex.txt

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@Echo off
set /p x= Enter a number: 
set extension=.txt
set first=file
for %%i in (0,1,%x%) DO ( 
set "filename=%first% + %i% + %extension%"
echo "%filename%"
del /q "D:\\%filename%"
pause
)
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some small syntactical errors are corrected below, but the main problem
was the lack of
[Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
to make variables be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time

The corrected script :

```
%echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p x=Enter a number:
set extension=.txt
set first=file
for /L %%i in (0,1,%x%) DO (
  set "filename=%first%%%i%extension%"
  echo !filename!
  del /q "D:\!filename!"
  pause
)
```